# How to update a Django model with a large CSV file (54 fields, ~5000 rows)?

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a model describing data center items (e.g. Racks, PDUs, patch panels, switches, servers, blades, ...). The data is exported regularly as CSV (once a month) and the export currently has close to 5000 lines and 54 fields per row.

For our Django App, roughly 80% of the rows are relevant: their equipment type must be in a pre-defined type list and the item must have a barcode (internal asset number) associated with it. The rest of the lines is skipped.

The model (see below) captures all of the available fields, even if they're not used. The reason for that is that the app, once it becomes productive, will have several models related to each other but fed from different data sources. Until now all of them are completely unrelated, the goal is to detect lint in the various databases and, over time, clean the data. Maybe in the future some data sources may even be declared authoritative so their data can be used to automatically generate updates for secondary databases whenever a primary representation changes.

In the app we currently upload the CSV file via form, here is a sample of the CSV (data anonymized):

```
"Name";"Serial Number";"Barcode";"Installation Date";"Model Name";"Description";"Manufacturer";"Part Number";"Manufacturer's Nameplate (W)";"Adjusted Nameplate (W)";"Location";"Room";"Row";"Floor Coordinates";"Rack";"U-Position";"U-Height";"Max Power Ports";"Product family";"Bay type";"Bay count";"Module type";"Weight";"Zero-based numbering";"Power supply";"Breaker Type";"Circuit Number";"Breaker Phase";"Breaker Panel";"Equipment type";"Port Description";"IP Address";"Order";"GeraeteSubTyp";"Datum";"Address";"RfC-Abbau";"Lodger";"GeraeteTyp";"SerialNr";"Techniker";"Bemerkung";"URL";"System-Status";"InventarNr";"SerialNrMotherboardCisco";"AssetID";"Connected to";"RfC-Aufbau";"Device Description";"Parent System";"Group";"Device Location";"Device Name";
"hostname1";"";"123456789";"01/01/2015";"MI-3230";"MyCorp Infrastructure 3230";"MyCorp";"";"300";"0";"U-16/Rack07/Row01/Room23/Provider2/Location1/Country1/";"23";"01";"";"07";"16";"2";;"";"";"";"";"17 kg";"";"";"";"";"";"";"Layer2 Network Gear";"";"";"";"";"01.01.2015";"";"";"";"Net";"3230545CZM4523";"TN2";"";"";"Active";"";"";"123456789";"987654321";"";"";"";"";"";"";
"hostname2";"";"987654321";"26/9/2014";"MI-3330";"MyCorp Infrastructure 3330";"MyCorp";"";"750";"750";"U-27/Rack16/Row13/Room05/Provider1/Location1/Country2/";"05";"13";"";"16";"27";"2";;"";"";"";"";"37.8 kg";"";"";"";"";"";"";"Generic Rack-mount Equipment";"";"";"";"";"2014.09.26";"";"";"";"Storage";"3330978BJI1037";"TN1";"2";"";"ReUse";"";"";"987654321";"123456789";"";"";"";"";"";"";
```

The data usually doesn't change much once it's in the database. Changes typically occur at lifecycle boundaries (hardware gets dismantled from active use) or it may be moved if reused or replaced if broken - say there's more or less 10 changes per month.

Adding new items to the database and recognizing existing entries (currently I'm skipping them) works like a charm - but it takes very long (currently 5 to 10 minutes and I'm not talking updates, yet!). Here's the view I have so far:

```
def update_sw_db(request):
    extra_content = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateStruxurewareDatabaseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            result_dict = {}
            add_list = []
            upd_list = []
            skip_list = []
            err_list = []
            all_fields = SWRecord().get_all_fields()
            field_list = []
            type_list = ['Blade', 'Blade Enclosure', 'Generic Rack-mount Equipment', 'Layer2 Network Gear', 'Layer3 Network Gear', 'Switch Enclosure', 'Switch Module']
            re_en_old = re.compile('\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}')
            re_de_old = re.compile('\d{1,4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,4}')
            re_en_new = re.compile('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
            for field in all_fields:
                field_list.append(field['name'])
            decoded_csv = codecs.iterdecode(form.cleaned_data['csv_file'], 'utf-8')
            # skip the first three lines (header lines)
            next(decoded_csv)
            next(decoded_csv)
            next(decoded_csv)
            reader = csv.reader(decoded_csv, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
            for row in reader:
                sw_record = SWRecord()
                err_message = ''
                if len(field_list) +1 != len(row):
                    # each row has a trailing empty element so it's off by one
                    # compared to the field list. If this condition is not met
                    # that's an error. Deal with it!
                    err_message = err_message + 'Error! row has %s elements (should be %s)! Offending row:\n%S\n' % (len(row), len(field_list) +1, row)
                else:
                    has_error = False
                    for col_idx in range(len(field_list)):
                        value = row[col_idx]
                        if col_idx == 3 or col_idx == 34:
                            date_items = ['', '', '']
                            split_char = ''
                            if value == '':
                                value = None
                                continue
                            elif re_en_old.search(value):
                                split_char = '/'
                                date_items = value.split(split_char)
                            elif re_de_old.search(value):
                                split_char = '.'
                                date_items = value.split(split_char)
                            elif re_en_new.search(value):
                                split_char = '-'
                                date_items = value.split(split_char)
                            else:
                                err_message = err_message + 'Error: strange date encountered: "%s"\n' % value
                                has_error = True
                            if not has_error:
                                for date_item in range(len(date_items)):
                                    date_items[date_item] = date_items[date_item].strip()
                                if len(date_items[0]) == 4 and len(date_items[2]) <= 2:
                                    year = date_items[0]
                                    month = date_items[1].zfill(2)
                                    day = date_items[2].zfill(2)
                                elif len(date_items[2]) == 4 and len(date_items[0]) <= 2:
                                    year = date_items[2]
                                    month = date_items[1].zfill(2)
                                    day = date_items[0].zfill(2)
                                elif len(date_items[2]) <= 2 and len(date_items[0]) <= 2:
                                    year = '20' + date_items[2].zfill(2)
                                    if split_char == '/':
                                        month = date_items[0].zfill(2)
                                        day = date_items[1].zfill(2)
                                    elif split_char == '.':
                                        month = date_items[1].zfill(2)
                                        day = date_items[0].zfill(2)
                                    else:
                                        err_message = err_message + 'Error: unknown split char: "%s", raw value="%s"\n' % (split_char, row[col_idx])
                                        has_error = True
                                elif date_items[2] == '207':
                                    year = '2017'
                                    month = date_items[1].zfill(2)
                                    day = date_items[0].zfill(2)
                                else:
                                    err_message = err_message + 'Error: strange date encountered: "%s"\n' % value
                                    has_error = True
                                # basic sanity check...
                                int_year = int(year)
                                int_month = int(month)
                                int_day = int(day)
                                try:
                                    new_date = datetime.datetime(year=int_year,month=int_month,day=int_day)
                                except ValueError as e:
                                    err_message = err_message + 'Error: invalid date: raw value="%s" decoded to: year="%s" month="%s day="%s"\n%s\n' % (row[col_idx], year, month, day, e)
                                    has_error = True
                                value = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
                        setattr(sw_record, field_list[col_idx], value)
                    if not has_error:
                        if sw_record.equipment_type in type_list and sw_record.barcode != '':
                            existing_set = SWRecord.objects.filter(barcode=sw_record.barcode)
                            if existing_set.count() == 0:
                                try:
                                    add_list.append(sw_record)
                                except:
                                    sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'Error: could not save SWRecord "%s", content: "%s"' % (sw_record, sw_record.to_dict())
                                    err_list.append(sw_record)
                                    raise
                            elif existing_set.count() == 1:
                                    #TODO: add updating code...
                                    existing_record = SWRecord.objects.get(barcode=sw_record.barcode)
                                    update_fields = []
                                    print('Updated fields: "%s"' % update_fields)
                                    sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'Skipped: Entry already existing: sw_record="%s", content="%s"' % (sw_record, sw_record.to_dict())
                                    skip_list.append(sw_record)
                            elif existing_set.count() > 1:
                                    sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'Error: duplicate AID: occurrences="%s"; SWRecord="%s", existing_set="%s"' % (existing_set.count(), sw_record, existing_set)
                                    err_list.append(sw_record)
                        else:
                            sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'Skipped: Entry not relevant: sw_record="%s", content="%s"' % (sw_record, sw_record.to_dict())
                            skip_list.append(sw_record)
                    else:
                        sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + err_message
                        err_list.append(sw_record)
            with transaction.atomic():
                # Use a list of indices (integers) to record any failed save attempts.
                # After adding remove those erred entry from add_list
                erred_indices = []
                # Loop over each result and invoke save() on each entry
                for index, add_result in enumerate(add_list):
                    try:
                        # save() method called on each member to create record
                        add_result.save()
                    except ValueError as e:
                        sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'ValueError encountered while trying to save SWRecord "%s", content: "%s"\n%s\n' % (sw_record, sw_record.to_dict(), e)
                        erred_indices.append(index)
                        err_list.append(sw_record)
                    except ValidationError as e:
                        sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'ValidationError encountered while trying to save SWRecord "%s", content: "%s"\n%s\n' % (sw_record, sw_record.to_dict(), e)
                        erred_indices.append(index)
                        err_list.append(sw_record)
                    except:
                        sw_record.remark = sw_record.remark + 'Unexcpected error encountered while trying to save SWRecord "%s", content: "%s"\n%s\n' % (sw_record, sw_record.to_dict(), sys.exc_info()[0])
                        erred_indices.append(index)
                        err_list.append(sw_record)
                        raise
                for index in reversed(erred_indices):
                    del add_list[erred_indices[index]]
            for k, v in {
                'with errors': err_list,
                'added': add_list,
                'updated': upd_list,
                'skipped': skip_list,
            }.items():
                if v:
                    result_dict.update({k: v})
            extra_content['result_dict'] = result_dict
        else:
            extra_content['form'] = form
    else:
        form = UpdateStruxurewareDatabaseForm()
        extra_content['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'damagecontrol/update_sw_db.html', extra_content)
```

Even if I use the same file again it doesn't take less time as I'm iterating over all of the rows and all of the fields - remember there are close to 5000 rows and 54 fields so we're talking about ~270,000 steps here. I'm fairly new to Python & Django (I have been using them for ~3 months now) and I've been searching the 'net and found all sorts of useful stuff - but unfortunately nothing that could answer my questions:

Can you point me to (I strongly believe there is at least one) a better approach to upload a CSV file, check for changes and apply them to the database? Better, in this case is simpler, faster but still reliable (look at the "date" conversion's I'm doing - unfortunately the field in the source database is free text and in the past it has been used "freely"...)

As the upload will occur in real life only once a month, performance is not top priority - if it takes 10 or 15 minutes, it takes 10 or 15 minutes. The most important question for me is: if I recognize that a SWRecord created from a CSV row is already in the database (the barcode can be safely assumed as pk here), how can I compare the contents of the new object with the one fetched from the database and how do I update the database, if there are differences?

We can assume that the CSV file is always correct. It is not pretty but it it is the truth.

Here, for completeness is the relevant excerpt from models.py:

```
class PrintableModel(models.Model):
    # define global fields
    created     = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified    = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    # Override save() to allow automatic saving of created / modified times
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(PrintableModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.to_dict())

    def to_dict(self):
        opts = self._meta
        data = {}
        for f in opts.concrete_fields + opts.many_to_many:
            if isinstance(f, ManyToManyField):
                if self.pk is None:
                    data[f.name] = []
                else:
                    data[f.name] = list(f.value_from_object(self).values_list('pk', flat=True))
            else:
                data[f.name] = f.value_from_object(self)
        return data

    # get all fields of the model for iterations in templates
    def get_all_fields(self, exclude_list):
        fields = []
        for f in self._meta.fields:
            fname = f.name
            # resolve picklists/choices, with get_xyz_display() function
            get_choice = 'get_'+fname+'_display'
            if hasattr( self, get_choice):
                value = getattr( self, get_choice)()
            else:
                try :
                    value = getattr(self, fname)
                except TCRecord.DoesNotExist:
                    value = None
            # only display fields with values and skip some fields entirely
            if f.editable and f.name not in exclude_list:
                fields.append(
                    {
                    'label':f.verbose_name,
                    'name':f.name,
                    'value':value,
                    }
                )
        return fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SWRecord(PrintableModel):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'StruxureWare Record'
        verbose_name_plural = 'StruxureWare Records'
        ordering = ('barcode', 'asset_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s (%s)' % (self.manufacturer, self.model_name, self.barcode)

    def get_all_fields(self):
        return super(SWRecord, self).get_all_fields(['id', 'created', 'modified'])

    # general management fields
    # CSV fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
    serial_number2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Serial Number', blank=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Barcode', blank=True)
    installation_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Installation Date') # Date Field?
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Model Name')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Description', blank=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Manufacturer')
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Part Number', blank=True)
    powerconsumption_manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Manufacturer\'s Nameplate (W)', blank=True)
    powerconsumption_adjusted = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Adjusted Nameplate (W)', blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Location')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Room')
    row = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Row', blank=True)
    floor_coordinates = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Floor Coordinates', blank=True)
    rack = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Rack', blank=True)
    u_position = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='U-Position', blank=True)
    u_height = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='U-Height', blank=True)
    max_powerports = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Max Power Ports', blank=True)
    product_family = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Product family', blank=True)
    bay_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Bay type', blank=True)
    bay_count = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Bay count', blank=True)
    module_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Module type', blank=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Weight')
    zerobased_numbering = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Zero-based numbering', blank=True)
    power_supply = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Power supply', blank=True)
    breaker_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Breaker Type', blank=True)
    circuit_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Circuit Number', blank=True)
    breaker_phase = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Breaker Phase', blank=True)
    breaker_panel = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Breaker Panel', blank=True)
    equipment_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Equipment type')
    port_description = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Port Description', blank=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4', verbose_name='IP Address', blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Order', blank=True)
    device_subtype = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='GeraeteSubTyp', blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Datum', blank=True, null=True) # Beware conversion!
    address = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Address', blank=True) # apparently never used...
    rfc_dismantling = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='RfC-Abbau', blank=True)
    lodger = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Lodger', blank=True) # for customer-owned property
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='GeraeteTyp', blank=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='SerialNr', blank=True)
    technician = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Techniker', blank=True)
    remark = models.TextField(verbose_name='Bemerkung', blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='URL', blank=True)
    system_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='System-Status', blank=True)
    inventory_number = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='InventarNr', blank=True)
    sn_ciscomb = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='SerialNrMotherboardCisco', blank=True)
    asset_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='AssetID', blank=True)
    connected_to = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Connected to', blank=True)
    rfc_installation = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='RfC-Aufbau', blank=True)
    device_description = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Device Description', blank=True)
    parent_system = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Parent System', blank=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Group', blank=True)
    device_location = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Device Location', blank=True)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Device Name', blank=True)
```

Thank you for taking your time to read through all of this...

Comment: Instead of parsing the mostly stable file over and over agin, you could consider creating and parsing a `diff` file instead.

Comment: @amain thanks for your quick reply. I am indeed considering a diff CSV as this would spare me a bunch of headaches - but create others on the other hand: I only have the complete CSV after an Export, so where do I get the base CSV from to compare the new export with? Would you recommend to create it from the current data stored in the Database?

Comment: If you can't produce a diff offline, I would stay with uploading the whole file then. It's not excessively large. I don't get your _true_ question though: You are already looking for the existence of the barcode. Just `save()` the record (depending on your schema, you might have to [force it as UPDATE or INSERT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update).

Comment: My main problem is that I can‘t trust the CSV entirely. The Barcode *should* be unique and theoretically this should make it a good candidate for a pk - but as I said: the source database doesn‘t constraints on it‘s fields. Like the „date“ fields, the barcode fields are plain text, too, so although new devices are usually entered with a barcode scanner, there‘s no protection against human error. Currently „barcode is set“  is the only check, there is no verification yet. Because of this I end up with two objects, if a barcode is in the database: sw_record (CSV) and existing_record (database)

Comment: So the true question is: with my two objects, sw_record (created from uploaded csv) and existing_record (fetched from the database because of barcode equality), how can I best compare all of their fields (both objects are instances of SWRecord) and, if there are fields with unequal contents, how can I update existing_record so its contents match sw_record?

Comment: You could implement an `update()` method similar to [dict.update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) in your `SWRecord` class, accepting objects of type `SWRecord`, `dict` or both. But you should have some true identifier at hand to avoid creating a mess. How else would you know which object to update? Maybe you find some combination of fields that always exists and is unique (multi-field key)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only comparing the barcodes with `SWRecord.objects.filter(barcode=sw_record.barcode)`, wouldn't it be smarter to create a list of barcodes present in the db **before** iterating over the rows and then checking the count of each row's barcode in that list?
A bit like so:

```
barcode_list = SWRecord.objects.values_list('barcode', flat=True)
for row in reader:
    barcode_count = barcodes_list.count(row['barcode'])
    if barcode_count==0:
        add_list.append(create_SWRecord_from_row(row)) # creates unsaved SWRecord
    elif barcode_count==1:
        update_list(update_SWRecord_from_row(row)) # prepares the update_data for an update
    else:
        deal_with_it(row) # oh god duplicate primary keys

with transaction.atomic():
    SWRecord.objects.bulk_create(add_list) # if you do not need the save() method
for pk, data in update_list.items():
    SWRecord.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(**data) # save() isn't called here either
```

Before saving, this would hit the database exactly once and not each time a row makes it through without an error. `bulk_create` does not call the `save()` method and hits the database once and thus is a **lot** faster.

Comment: That might be some good advice to boost performance as it doesn‘t create SWRecords for all the rows. Echoing all ~5000 rows back to the user might be useful for my early development stage but for production it might be better to reduce the amount of rows to the absolute minimum before starting to build objects. This is also a good opportunity to export the complexity from the view function into more appropriate helper functions. I find that very intriguing if I can find a solution that leaves failed create_ or update_SWRecord attempts in some kind of err_list that I can pass back to the user.

Comment: For the collecting the errors: you can always pass whatever is collecting the errors to the helper functions -- or you use class based view for this and declare a class-wide error list (much like forms do it). A CBV + helper functions would make this a hell of a lot easier to unit-test, too. Strictly speaking, the logic for processing the csv file can/should be delegated to a completely different class (all it needs is the file itself).

Comment: After thinking a bit another question crossed my mind: at the end of your suggestion you avoid the save() function in both cases. At the moment I‘m relying on save() to automatically update the „created“ and „modified“ fields inherited from the PrintableModel abstract class. I need to keep that in mind while searching for my solution... thanks for the pointer to CBVs, I‘ll investigate that direction, too!

Comment: If you rely on the `save()` method, by all means, use it. You've said it yourself; time is not the enemy. Though, you could add the required data for those fields before the `bulk_create`/`update`. The main focus of your work should be filtering out all those rows that match or are comparable to objects in the database as efficiently as possible. Saving a couple of times vs one big bulk insert won't make much of a difference.